# Android Game Menu

Tags: android, button

I'm new to android programming.I need help with my code.As you can see, i have a menu, after clicking a button which i made using onDraw method and onTouchEvent.

```
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
    CoordCheck cc = new CoordCheck();
    Log.d(TAG, "Coords: X=" + event.getX() + ",Y=" + event.getY()+"choice="+glb.getChoice());

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        float x, y;
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        //
        // MAIN MENU
        //
        if(glb.getChoice()==0)
        {
            if (cc.ifMenu_exit(x, y))
            {
                thread.setRunning(false);
                ((Activity)getContext()).finish();
            }

            else if (cc.ifMenu_pagsasanay(x,y))
            {
                thread.menu_pagsasanay();
            }
        }
        //
        // PAGSASANAY MENU
        //
        if(glb.getChoice()==1)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"PAGSASANAY MENU");
            if (cc.ifPagsasanay_pitik(x, y))
            {       
                pitik = new PitikBulagAnimation(
                        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.hand_sprites) 
                        , 450, 60   // initial position
                        , 350, 41   // width and height of sprite
                        , 50, 6);   // FPS and number of frames in the animation
                Log.d(TAG,"pitik");
                thread.pitikAnimation();
            }
            else if (cc.ifPagsasanay_jnp(x, y))
            {
                jnp = new JNPAnimation(
                        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ai_sprite) 
                        , 550, 70   // initial position
                        , 283, 41   // width and height of sprite
                        , 50, 4);   // FPS and number of frames in the animation
                Log.d(TAG,"jnp");
                thread.jnpAnimation();
            }
            if(cc.ifBackButton(x, y))
            {
                thread.menu_main();
            }
```

err.. glb.getChoice if value is zero, it means the view contains the main menu. my problem is, if i clicked "pagsasanay" button(inside main menu), i can go to Pagsasanay menu and choice in glb class will be set to 1, but after getting there, the event.getX() value remains therefore clicking another button which is exactly in the same coordinate as the "pagsasanay" button

Answer (score 0):

These views you use as buttons should have the onClick property set in the xml.
The onClick property identifies the method to call when the view is clicked and within that method you can decide what action to take, offer a new menu or other action.
You can code onClickListeners to each view if you are more java oriented but imho that is just more code to write. On the other hand sometimes it makes sense to code the listeners, it just depends on what you are doing. From what I see of your code so far, go for the xml defined onClick property.